# Edit existing pdf and send for download using iTextSharp and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

So I've been trying to use iTextSharp to edit an existing pdf file. I've been able to do that using the following code below.

```
            public static void AddTextToPdf(string inputPdfPath, string outputPdfPath, string name, string mID, string dj)
    {
        //variables
        string pathin = inputPdfPath;
        string pathout = outputPdfPath;

        //create PdfReader object to read from the existing document
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pathin))
        //create PdfStamper object to write to get the pages from reader 
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(pathout, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            //select two pages from the original document
            reader.SelectPages("1");

            //gettins the page size in order to substract from the iTextSharp coordinates
            var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

            // PdfContentByte from stamper to add content to the pages over the original content
            PdfContentByte pbover = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

            //add content to the page using ColumnText
            Font font = new Font();
            font.Size = 45;
            font.Color = Colors.stringToBaseColor("224,90,71");

            //Do Name
            DrawText(50, 260, pageSize, pbover, name, font);

            //Do Date
            font.Size = 16;
            DrawText(200, 402, pageSize, pbover, dj, font);

            //Do mID
            DrawText(180, 422, pageSize, pbover, mID, font);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to integrate this into an MVC application that will send the revised PDF file for download, but I've ran into a mental block. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You now have the edited PDF saved to the disk. What do you want to do next? What do you mean by send to download?

Comment: What I am thinking is that instead of saving the file, modify the method to have it returned at which point I can send it off for download in the mvc controller. This will save me the hassle of saving the file to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(pathout, FileMode.Create)))
```

simply replace `FileStream` with `MemoryStream` and return byte array from memory stream in the end of your method:

```
...
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream))
{
    ...
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

You could easily find it in google with `itextsharp get byte array`.